# ActionBarSherlock and swipelistview using gradle

Tags: gradle, actionbarsherlock, swipeview

I need to use `ActionBarSherlock` and `SwipeListView` in my project. I added following dependencies to build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile('com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview:swipelistview:1.0-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
   transitive = true
}
```

I get following error: `Attribute xxx has already been defined`. I suppose that problem is because `SwipeListView` uses appcompat-v7 as a dependency and `ActionBarSherlock` and v7 are not compatible as you can see [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/999).

What's the proper way to use both `ActionBarSherlock` and `SwipeListView` in my project using gradle?

Answer (score 0):

I excluded the appcompat-v7 lib during build. It seems to work so far. But I'm afraid it might crash on some devices

```
compile ('com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview:swipelistview:1.0-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
        transitive = true
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
    }
```

I have opened an issue: https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview/issues/191 to see if the dependency is needed or not.